# How block .@ operator?

Tags: groovy

I work on a sandbox Groovy and I want to block the `.@` operator. I'm using a `SecureASTCustomizer` and I've written a custom `SecureASTCustomizer.ExpressionChecker` where I removed authorization.

My problem is: I can't find a way to detect the `@` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.SecureASTCustomizer
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.SecureASTCustomizer.ExpressionChecker as EC
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.AttributeExpression

def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
def secure = new SecureASTCustomizer()
secure.addExpressionCheckers ({ expr ->
    !(expr instanceof AttributeExpression)
} as SecureASTCustomizer.ExpressionChecker)
config.addCompilationCustomizers(secure)

def shell = new GroovyShell(config)
shell.evaluate '''
class A { int val }
def a = new A(val:123)
a.@val
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

The [groovy-sandbox](http://groovy-sandbox.kohsuke.org/) library supports intercepting this.

(`SecureASTCustomizer` is not actually secure at all. Do not try to use it for a sandbox.)